# Learning to read Chinese but not speak

Tags: characters, learning, writing, reading

Are there good resources for learning Chinese from the ground up with a bias torwards reading and not speaking. For me the ability to read would be much more useful. Pronunciation is the hardest part and it seems like it would be much faster to learn if I could just learn grammar and characters. Is this approach advisable?

Comment: You could do that. It's what people do if they have impaired hearing abilities. I don't think you could go faster if you sacrifice auditory leaning. But then again, Chinese writing system is not really phonetic so who could tell...